How can I use email with django-allauth without mail server?
I'd like to configure django-allauth in such a way that users have to register with email and password but the Django project does not have to provide a mail server and no emails are transmitted (no registration confirmation, no password reset link, etc.). How do I have to configure django-allauth.
